# syntax error in query

Tags: c#

I am new to programming and is developing a new desktop database applcation in Access, I am trying to insert data into a table. I had two datetime picker and I read the value from it as

```
jobcodedatabean.PaperRecievedate1 = dtpjobcodedate.Value.Date;
jobcodedatabean.Shipmenentdate = dtpshipmentdate.Value.Date;
```

and I had passed the databean to a function

```
 public void addaction(JobCodeDataBean jobcodedatabean)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(jobcodedatabean.Shipmenentdate.ToString());

        try
        {

            OleDbConnection oleDbConnection1 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connString);
            oleDbConnection1.Open();
            OleDbCommand oleDbCommand1 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO jobcodemastertable (jobcode ,customercode,totaltrip,shipmentdate,fromPlace, destination,description ,packagetype ,noofpackage ,contactperson ,jobecodedate ) Values ('" + jobcodedatabean.Jobcode + "', '" + jobcodedatabean.Customercode + "' ," + jobcodedatabean.Totaltrip + "," + jobcodedatabean.Shipmenentdate + " ,'" + jobcodedatabean.Fromplace + "','" + jobcodedatabean.Destination + "','" + jobcodedatabean.Description + "','" + jobcodedatabean.Typeofpackage + "','" + jobcodedatabean.Noofpackages + "','" + jobcodedatabean.Contactperson + "'," + jobcodedatabean.PaperRecievedate1 + ") ", oleDbConnection1);
            oleDbCommand1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            oleDbCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();

            oleDbConnection1.Close();

       }
       catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e);

        }
```

but i am getting the exception at the query

```
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '2/16/2012 12:00:00 AM'.
```

In access the date fields are in short date format

Please somebody help to sort out my mistake

Comment: why dont you use string.format for this, this is so hard to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Incorrect quotations. To avoid these kinds of mistakes, use ordered parameters:

```
var myCommand = new OleDbCommand(
    "INSERT INTO MyTable(someDateField, someTextField, someNumberField) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
);

myCommand.Parameters.Add(DateTime.Now);
myCommand.Parameters.Add("Some text");
myCommand.Parameters.Add(123);
```

Using parameters also helps protect against [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). In your example, if one of the strings contained an apostrophe, it would fail unless you correctly converted it to two apostrophes. With parameters these are escaped correctly automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to enclose dates in quotes:

```
... ",'" + jobcodedatabean.Shipmenentdate + "' ,'" ...
... "','" + jobcodedatabean.PaperRecievedate1 + "') " ...
```

Note single quotes around both dates.